# Switching a line of batteries with MOSFETs

Tags: batteries, mosfet, switches, ground

I want to build up a small batterybank made of modules. The modules should be separated and in series as shown in the image. Is it possible to switch the total 48V if the MOSFETs are only connected to the last module and have only the ground potential of the batterypack they are connected to?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for. From the schematics it looks like a series connection of 2 batteries. If you open the loop at some point the load will not see any voltage.

About the mosfet, you need to guarantee that its driver is powered in every condition (also with mosfet open, otherwise you can't close it anymore). Then, this is a high side mosfet so you have to drive it correctly. Usually, for this kind of thing it is easier to use N-Mos and switch the negative pole.